# Optimality criterion for unconstrained convex optimization problems

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, problem-solving

Consider a general convex optimization problem:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{minimize}}
& & f_0(x) \\
& \text{subject to}
& & f_i(x) \leq 0, \; i = 1, \ldots, m.
& & h_i(x) = 0, \; i = 1, \ldots, p.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
of finding an $x$ that minimizes the objective function among all $x$ that satisfy
the inequality ($f_i:R^n\to R$) and equality ($h_i:R^n\to R$) constraints. Suppose $x\in R^n$ (optimization variable) and $f_0:R^n\to R$ (objective function). Let $X$ denote the feasible set, i.e.,
$$X = \{x | f_i(x) \leq 0, i = 1, . . . ,m, h_i(x) = 0, i = 1, \dots, p\}.$$
Suppose $f_0$ is differentiable. Then it can be proved that $x$ is optimal iff $x\in X$ and
$$\nabla f_0(x)^T(y - x) \geq 0\text{ for all } y\in X$$
Given this, I want to prove that for an unconstrained problem (i.e., $m = p = 0$), the above condition reduces to
$$\nabla f_0(x) = 0$$
Here is the proof according to "Convex Optimization - Boyd and Vandenberghe" book:

> Suppose x is optimal, which means here that $x \in domf_0$, and for
>   all feasible $y$ we have $\nabla f_0(x)^T(y - x) \geq 0$. Since $f_0$
>   is differentiable, its domain is (by definition) open, so all $y$
>   sufficiently close to $x$ are feasible. Let us take $y = x-t\nabla f_0(x)$, 
>   where $t \in R$ is a parameter. For $t$ small and positive,
>   $y$ is feasible, and so $\nabla f_0(x)^T (y - x) = -t||\nabla f_0(x)||^2\geq 0$, 
>   from which we conclude $\nabla f_0(x)=0$.

What I don't understand here is why any $y$ near $x$ is feasible. Since $domf_0$ is an open set, I am convinced that any $y$ near $x$ is in $domf_0$. But this doesn't mean that $y\in X$ since $domf_0 \subseteq X$ does not hold in general. So we need to find another way. The feasible set is a subset of the problem's domain:
$$X\subseteq D \text{ where } D=\bigcap\limits_{i=0}^mdomf_i\bigcap\limits_{i=0}^pdomh_i$$
If we can prove that $X$ is open then any $y$ near $x$ is in $X$. Finally, is the final inequality at the end of the proof true? It doesn't affect the result but shouldn't it be:
$$-t||\nabla f_0(x)||^2\leq 0\ \ \ \ ?$$

Comment: $y-x$ should be replaced by $v$ with $v\in T_xh(x)$ and if $f_i(x)=0$ then $<v,\nabla f_i(x)>$ should be non positive.

Comment: I must be missing something. You're asking about the *unconstrained case*, but then you are referring to $X$, $f_i$, $h_i$, etc. There are no constraints! So $X=\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant So, what you are implying is that $x\in domf_0\Rightarrow y\in domf_0\Rightarrow y\in X$ since $domf_0$ is open and $domf_0=X=D=R^n$. Is that correct?

Comment: Of course. Again, you're asking about the unconstrained version of the problem. Why are you even talking about $f_i$ and $h_i$?

Comment: @MichaelGrant I understand. It doesn't make sense. Thanks for stressing this out.